# Plotting a line using d3 and an JSON data object passed from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

I'm pushing the boundaries of experience here and cant see what I am doing wrong.

I'm pulling a bunch of data from a DB in rails, converting it to JSON and trying to plot it in  d3.

The data is a simple JSON of {date => number} and the data is fine.

I'm doing something wrong with d3 in the loop at the bottom of the code but cant see what.

The axes plot fine but I can't get the line to draw.

Here is my code:

```
var data = <%= @signups.to_json.html_safe %>;

var date, signups

var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%Y").parse;

var x = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(date)
    .y(signups)
    .interpolate("linear");

var svg = d3.select(".container").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Find range of data for domain
var min_date = Infinity, max_date = -Infinity;
var min_signups = Infinity, max_signups = -Infinity;
var x;

$.each(data, function(key, value) {

    temp = parseDate(key)
    if( temp < min_date) min_date = temp;
    if( temp > max_date) max_date = temp;

    if( +value < min_signups) min_signups = +value;
    if( +value > max_signups) max_signups = +value;

});

x.domain([min_date, max_date]);
y.domain([0, max_signups]);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
.append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Price ($)");

svg.append("path")

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
    date = parseDate(key);
    signups = value;

    d3.select("path")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
        .x(date)
        .y(signups)
        .interpolate("linear"));    
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: colster, you should accept Lars' answer to make it easier for others to find. It helped me when I found it.

Answer (score 1):

The D3 way would be to pass all your data to a suitable line generator. This is fairly simple in your case, you just need to convert the object that contains all the data to an array that D3 can work with using [`d3.entries()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_entries).

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
             .x(function(d) { return x(parseDate(d.key)); })
             .y(function(d) { return y(d.value); });
svg.selectAll("path").data([d3.entries(data)])
   .enter().append("path").attr("d", line);
```

As you have only a single line, you could also use `.datum()` to bind the data, but using `.data()` leaves you the option of passing in data for more lines later.

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dtmML/1/). When modifying this, make sure that you create the line *before* adding the axes, otherwise D3's data matching won't work with the default matching and you won't get any lines. To fix this, you could supply a matching function, but to start with it's much easier to keep to this order.

Comment: Thanks Lars, still no joy though.  I changed the first 'path' in the svg line above to be enclosed in quotes which I assume is correct.  But I don't get any path generation at all.

Comment: Yes, sorry, that was a typo. You also need to parse the date -- I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks Lars.  For some reason i still don't get any path elements in the DOM at all.  The data is all there and appears fine.  I've just put it in a JSfiddle and get the same thing http://jsfiddle.net/colster/dtmML/

Comment: Ok, I didn't quite know your data format. Will update the answer.

Comment: No go still.  I'll download the unminified d3 later and track it.  Not getting any line at all just <path></path>.  Thanks for your help though :)

Comment: Did you have a look at the fiddle I include in the answer?

Comment: Lars, how did you learn about d3.  I'm really keen to learn but don't think I've ever seen a reference to having to define the line before the axes.  I really appreciate your help

Comment: This is not a requirement -- it's just easier to do it this way as a beginner. Change it and see what happens. In particular have a look at what the selections contain.